# MVC - Posting From a Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, partial-views

I have an MVC web application and I'm using a partial view. This consists of a series of criteria and associated checkboxes.

[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usU1H.png)

Currently a checkbox is checked and the save button clicked, posting via this custom action

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult SaveParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteria(int participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId, bool response)
    {
        var participationMeasurementTime =
            repository.GetParticipationMeasurementTime(participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId);

        repository.SaveParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteria(participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId, response);

        unitOfWork.Save();
        var vm = GetParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteriaVM(participationMeasurementTime.ParticipationMeasurementTimeId);
        return PartialView("ParticipationMeasurementTimesCriteria", vm);

    }
```

Which routes to this method in the repository:

```
public void SaveParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteria(int participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId, bool response)
    {
        var participationMeasurementTimeCriteria = Context.ParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteria
            .First(x => x.ParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId == participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId);
        participationMeasurementTimeCriteria.Response = response;
        participationMeasurementTimeCriteria.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        participationMeasurementTimeCriteria.ModifiedBy = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    }
```

My objective is to streamline the process by only having one save button that updates all of them. There could be any number of criteria.

I've tried using JQuery to fire the action when the checkbox is updated.

I've tried creating a new custom action in the controller to take a list of criteria and update them, as shown below.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult SaveParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteria(List<ParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteria> participationMeasurementTimeCriterias, int participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId)
    {
        var participationMeasurementTime =
            repository.GetParticipationMeasurementTime(participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId);
        foreach (var criteria in participationMeasurementTimeCriterias)
        {
            var participationMeasurementTimeCriteria =
                participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaRepository.GetById(criteria.ParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteriaId);

            participationMeasurementTimeCriteriaRepository.Update(criteria);
        }
        unitOfWork.Save();
        var vm = GetParticipationMeasurementTimeCriteriaVM(participationMeasurementTime.ParticipationMeasurementTimeId);
        return PartialView("ParticipationMeasurementTimesCriteria", vm);

    }
```

But now I'm at a loss. Clearly there are gaps in my knowledge pertaining both to partial views and mvc in general, in regards to posting a list of entities from a view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pass-dynamically-added-html-table-records-list-to-controller/